# F# equivalent of Haskell scanl/scanr

Tags: haskell, f#, fold

Is there an F# equivalent of the Haskell `scanl`/`scanr`? These functions perform a fold but they report all intermediate accumulator states in the form of a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are [`List.scan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370366.aspx) and [`List.scanBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340287).